# Access Android Keystore (Biometrics) from Kotlin Native

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-native

is it possible to access the Android Keystore from a Kotlin Native compiled library?

I would like to use the BiometricPrompt with a CryptoObject for server validated authentication.

Does someone has an example code?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose this can be done via JNI, the same way as you would access it from C/C++(like [here](https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1245)). Kotlin/Native does not provide "a simple way" to use Java libraries from native code, it's about using native libraries in Kotlin-written code.